# Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am getting the following error in the browser console when trying to load my app. Can anyone explain why it is not finding react?

`Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined`

I am using webpack to bundle my code. The bundle itself is passing ok.

webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/app.js'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/assets/styles/main.less')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less"
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true,
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  externals: /^[a-z\-0-9]+$/
};
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Are you requiring in react in your source code?

Comment: what @JoeAttardi said, and a copy of your package.json would be great

Comment: Maybe you forget to install babel-preset-react?
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
externals: {
  "react": "React"
}
```

Or if you use ReactDOM:

```
externals: {
  "react": "React",
  "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
}
```

Comment: This will exclude it from the bundle which would cause the error OP is seeing. This tells Webpack not to bundle React, but to expect that React will be available globally (in the browser it would `window.React`).

Comment: @JoelKinzel If using that externals config and then loading React as `<script src="...">` on the HTML, how would window.React be defined? Is this expected to be defined by the library itself?

Comment: I have that posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72427753/using-externals-in-webpack-gives-error-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier