# Using 'externals' in Webpack gives error "failed to resolve module specifier"

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm testing a library that is exported as a module (by Webpack) with something like

```
// myLib.js
const a = 1;
export { a as myVal };
```

My script for the page is

```
// index.js
import { myVal } from 'my-lib'

console.log (myVal)
```

In `webpack.config.js` I have `externals: { myLib: 'myLib' }`. In my `index.html`, I would have

```
...
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/myLib"></script>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
...
```

This leads to run time error of `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "myLib". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

This is because despite the library has been loaded onto the page, it is not referenced by the name `myLib`.

What's the proper way to set up Webpack so that when I import `'myLib'` in `index.js`, it knows I mean import from `'http://unpkg.com/myLib'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to import the whole module and the make it a global variable, like so in `index.html`

```
...
  <script type="module">
    import * as myLib from 'https://unpkg.com/myLib'
    window.myLib = myLib
  </script>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
...
```

Another solution seems to be to generate modules as outputs

```
externals: { myLib: 'https://unpkg.com/myLib' }
experiments: { outputModule: true },
```

This gives you `.mjs` files. You'll see the first line in the output file with something like

```
import * as __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_https_unpkg_com_myLib_9592ca0f__ from "https://unpkg.com/myL";
```

This allows you to continue to use `import { myVal } from 'myLib'` in your code, while the compiled file substitutes `myLib` for the URL.

**Note**: This `externals` setting will generate an error if you do not output as modules. The generated file will have the line `module.exports = https://unpkg.com/myLib`, which is invalid JS syntax. If you put `` around the URL, syntax becomes valid, but what should be your module is just a string, i.e. `module.export` has a string value.

**Note**: This approach doesn't work well with `HttpWebpackPlugin` yet, as the injected script tags does not add `type="module"` for your module output files. You'll need to do this manually by specifying `scriptLoading: 'module'` (v5.5.0)

*Results from webpack 5.72.1*